# ES6 Default value parameter for callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have several functions with optional callback:

```
let myFunc = (callback) => {
  callback = callback || (() => {});
  // do something...
  callback();
}
```

**What is the best way to write the callback default parameter?**

None of the following solutions satisfy me much:

#### 1 If callback defined:

```
  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(); 
  }
```

Not compact at all!

#### 2 Utility function:

```
let safeFunc = (callback) => {
  return callback || (() => {});
};

let myFunc = (callback) => {
  // do something...
  safeFunc(callback)();
}
```

but the problem is that in between `this` has changed, and it matters in my case.

#### 3 Using `call`

```
let myFunc = (callback) => {
  // do something...
  safeFunc(callback).call(this);
}
```

Not very user friendly.

#### 4 Creating ID function

```
const ID = () => {};

let myFunc = (callback=ID) => {
  // do something...
  callback();
}
```

Has external dependency, not very functionnal, though probably the best choice.

Comment: There isn't necessarily a "best" way. 1 and 4 are good solutions, but note that they are not equivalent. If a value that is not a function is passed, 4 will throw and error, 1 won't.

Comment: I can't see how this question is a duplicate of the referenced one. Also I don't understand why there are so many down votes out there in the answers.

Comment: I think a better way for 4 would be `callback = () => void 0`. It resolves to `undefined` and we are returning explictly and also leaving empty { } will give errors in eslint and jslint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling directly `Function()` constructor looks meaningful:

```
let myFunc = (callback = Function()) => {
  // do something...
  callback();
}
```

Calling `Function()` returns a noop function:

```
let noopFunc = Function()
noopFunc() // => undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option.

#### 5 Just an if check..

```
  if (callback) callback();
```

If you want to prevent calling the callback twice, another utility function here I've called callIt, it also handles passing arguments, and if `this` is important also to prevent using bind, just pass `this`..

```js
function callIt(that, fn) {
  if (fn) fn.apply(that, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,2));
}


//Test Object
function Test() {
  this.test = 'Test';
}

Test.prototype.calltest = function (callback) {
  callIt(this, callback, 1, 2, 3);
}

var t = new Test();
t.calltest(
  function (a,b,c) { 
    console.log('this.test = ', this.test); 
    console.log('args = ', a, b, c);
  }
);
```

Comment: Which could actually be shortened with `callback && callback();`

Comment: Ain't there a way to avoid having to repeat `callback`?

Comment: need to check if argument is a function - if (typeof callback === 'function')

Answer (score -1):

// ES6 way:(default parameters)

```
function(callback=()=>{}) {
    if(typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do `typeof callback` anyway, why have a default value?

Comment: I thought I tried this before but apparently not. I'm accepting yours because this is certainly the most natural.

Comment: @FelixKling `typeof` checks if the passed `callback` parameter is a function, not if the default value is a function.

Comment: @PierreSpring: Of course. That's not what my comment was implying. My point is that if you are already verifying the type of the argument, then there is no need to specify an empty function as default value.